# Why the result of this program is 3 "born"?And 4 dead

Tags: c++, class, destructor, copy-constructor, construct

This is main.cpp:

```cpp
int main() {

    Person arr[2] = {
        Person(18,180),
        Person(20,173)
    };
    arr[0]+arr[1];

    return 0;
}
```

This is Person.h:

```cpp
class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    int height;
public:
    Person(int age=20,int height=180);
    ~Person();
    void operator+(Person);
};
```

And this is Person.cpp:

```cpp
Person::Person(int age,int height) {
    (*this).age = age;
    (*this).height = height;
    cout << "I'm born.\n";
}

Person::~Person() {
    cout << "I'm dead.\n";
}

void Person::operator+(Person a) {
    Person result;
    result.age = (*this).age + a.age;
    result.height = (*this).height + a.height;
    cout << result.age << endl;
    cout << result.height << endl;
}
```

Why the result of this program is 3 "born"?And 4 dead?
What are the procedures of initializing the array of objects 'arr'?

Comment: `result.age = (*this).age + a.age;` --> `result.age = age + a.age;`. You are just obfuscating your code with that explicit `this` dereference (which would in any case be better as `this->age`).. `(*this).age` is just *odd*.

Comment: The default copy constructor does not provide "I'm born by copy.\n" feedback.

Comment: It compiles here: [https://ideone.com/nHKZ30](https://ideone.com/nHKZ30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing born person is a clone! Note `operator+` take an argument by value, so the copy constructor is called (the default one in this case). To see this add

```
Person::Person(const Person &p) {
    this->age = p.age;
    this->height = p.height;
    cout << "I'm a clone.\n";
}
```

to your code - then it is clear why there are 4 people dead in the end. A better idea is you have your odd operator to have this signature to avoid copies and be explicit:

```
void Person::operator+(const Person &a) const;
```

Also, no point in using `*this` when you have the arrow operator.

Answer (score 1):

In the `operator+` the second argument of the addition, which is the first parameter, is passed by value, and so is called the copy constructor (which is not redefined and so you are not taking track of the object build with it) in order to build it, and so at the end of the function call that object is destructed (and so this is your 4th "hidden" dead person)

Answer (score 0):

Let;s count together the number of constructor and destructor calls.

In thsi declaration of an array

```
Person arr[2] = {
    Person(18,180),
    Person(20,173)
};
```

the constructor is called two times because two objects of the class are being created. Here is taken place the elision of calls of the copy constructor.

In this call

```
arr[0]+arr[1];
```

there is used the following function

```
void Person::operator+(Person a) {
    Person result;
    result.age = (*this).age + a.age;
    result.height = (*this).height + a.height;
    cout << result.age << endl;
    cout << result.height << endl;
}
```

The argument arr[1] is passed to the function by value calling the implicitly defined copy constructor. So a third object of the class is created.

Within the function there is created a fourth object in this declaration

```
    Person result;
```

So four objects were created three of them using the constructor with parameters and one with the copy constructor. So as a result four destructors were also called.

The operator should be declared and defined at least like

```
Person Person::operator +( const Person &a) const {
    return Person( age + a.age, height + a.height );
}
```

On the other hand it is better to make the constructor explicit. For example

```
explicit Person(int age=20,int height=180) : age( age ), height( height )
{
}
```